# Livedata Data Change Pattern

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-architecture-components

I have a doubt.If i have a method that make asynchronous call to an api and converts the results of it to livedata object and in another place i am updating my recyclerview when data changes, then every time call to this method  will update recyclerview or ,for eg:if url stays same then it won't update the recyclerview;Pls help.
Here is the code for observing data in Mainactivity onCreate method.

```
 JsonViewModel model = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(JsonViewModel.class);
    model.getData("top_rated").observe(this, data -> {
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new MovieRecyclerViewAdapter(this,data));
    });
```

Here is the JsonViewModel class

```
public class JsonViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

private JsonLivedata data;
public JsonViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    data=new JsonLivedata();
}

public LiveData<List<Movie>> getData(String path) {
    data.loadData(path);
    return data;
}
}
```

Here is the JsonLivedata class

```
public class JsonLivedata extends LiveData<List<Movie>> {
private static final String TAG = "JsonLivedata";

public JsonLivedata() {

}

public void loadData(String path){
    Log.d(TAG, "loadData: Called");
    new AsyncTask<String,Void,List<Movie>>(){
        @Override
        protected List<Movie> doInBackground(String... path) {
            List<Movie> allTopMovies= JsonResponseFetcher.makeAsyncQueryForMovies(path[0]);
            return allTopMovies;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Movie> movies) {
            setValue(movies);
        }
    }.execute(path);
}

}
```

And here is the method that call livedata loaddata method

```
changeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            model.getData("popular");
        }
    });
```

Or I am doing things wrongly.Can anyone suggest

Comment: Don't set a new adapter each time there is a change

Answer (score 0):

First create adapter instance & set to `RecyclerView`

```
JsonViewModel model = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(JsonViewModel.class);
MovieRecyclerViewAdapter movieRecyclerViewAdapter = new MovieRecyclerViewAdapter(this, dataList)
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(movieRecyclerViewAdapter);
```

Then do this on data changes

```
    model.getData("top_rated").observe(this, data -> {
       dataList.clear();
       dataList.addAll(data);
       movieRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    });
```